# Focus hWnd of another application

Tags: winapi, input, focus, setfocus

Is it possible to change focus inside a different application? I'm talking about the distinct views (data lists, custom views), not main windows. These also have handles, spy++ shows them properly and stuff, but when I've tried setting `SetFocus()`, is was no good. Does `SetFocus()` only work for main windows or what is amiss? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN article:

> The window must be attached to the calling thread's message queue

You'll need AttachThreadInput() first.  GetWindowThreadProcessId() to get the thread that owns the window.

Comment: Oh sweet, I was afraid it's a no go. Thanks, I should not really skip straight to the examples next time. Just a follow up: is calling the attach detectable by the original app?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, click the "Ask Question" button.  And don't forget to mention why this is important.

Comment: It is a bad idea to attach threads that were not designed to be attached. It can lead to deadlocks.